# Problems With NVIDIA binary 389.40 and Nouveau driver on 17.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors

i kinda have a unique problem with the nouveau(xorg)-server and the nvidia-384.90 driver.

So the Problem is the following,

With the Xorg Server / Wayland i dont get an output on my DisplayPort Monitor but on my DVI-I + VGA Adapter Monitor, i get an output. Also with the nouveau driver there is a lot of Stuttering, wich doesnt appear with the Nvidia Driver.

With the Nvidia Driver i get an output on my DisplayPort Monitor but not on my DVI-I + VGA Adapter Monitor.

Im Using Ubuntu 17.10 and an eGPU GTX770 on an Lenovo X230T.

EDIT: Im Sorry ist not Xorg its Wayland.

Comment: I am sorry you have having this problem but if no one has any better advice you might want to file a bug report with Nvidia - https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/

Comment: I will try it. Still this doesnt gives an answer to  my nouveau problem.

Comment: I missed you were using nouveau, in that case you would file a bug report on launchpad.

Comment: sir what version of ubuntu are u using? it's *very important* because, since 16.04... ubuntu doesnt use xorg anymore

Comment: Like in my Post im using 17.10

Answer (score 0):

So basically i got it run under Linux Deepin 15.5 and Debian Stretch XFCE4, so there would be no need for to it under Ubuntu 17.10, but it should only be a new xorg.conf file, at least with that i got it run under debian and deepin.